# How to add sympy symbols to dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sympy

so i am trying to add a sympy symbol(b) to all the values in a dataframe column but it does not seem to work.

These are the codes:

```
import sympy as sp
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('salary.xlsx')
b = sp.symbols('b')

def fne():
    for i in range(len(df)): 
        print((df.loc[i, "salary"] - (50+df.loc[i, "years"]*b))**2)
fne()
```

But the result i got was:

```
(38.0 - 11*b)**2
(27.3 - 6*b)**2
(25.3 - 7*b)**2
(46.4 - 20*b)**2
(37.7 - 8*b)**2
```

What i want is the actual value itself so for e.g the first result would look something like this:

```
(38.0−11)^2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've told a number of other posters that `sympy` and `numpy` are not integrated.  `sympy` objects work in `numpy` arrays to the extent that they can be treated as Python objects.  Looks like the same applies to `pandas`.

In an `isympy` session, I have symbol:

```
In [268]: tau                                                                                        
Out[268]: τ

In [269]: tau**2                                                                                     
Out[269]: 
 2
τ 

In [270]: import pandas as pd                                                                        

In [271]: S = pd.Series([tau, 1*tau, tau**2])                                                        

In [272]: S                                                                                          
Out[272]: 
0       tau
1       tau
2    tau**2
dtype: object

In [273]: S.values                                                                                   
Out[273]: array([tau, tau, tau**2], dtype=object)

In [274]: [i for i in S]                                                                             
Out[274]: 
⎡       2⎤
⎣τ, τ, τ ⎦
In [282]: S.tolist()                                                                                 
Out[282]: 
⎡       2⎤
⎣τ, τ, τ ⎦
```

A Series (and dataframe) stores values as numpy arrays (to the extent possible).  Notice that the display of both the array and series is "plain".  It's only when I display the elements on their own that I get the `sympy` formatting.  Object dtype arrays use the `repr(i)` to format the `i` element.

```
In [276]: print(repr(tau**2))                                                                        
tau**2
```